# Prevent specific string from spliting

Tags: java

I want to split these string except spend:1 and other "spend"s;

My txt file :

```
date : 1
day : monday
spend : 4

date : 2
day :  tuesday
spend : 1
```

I have retrieved these through search. I give input e.g input : 1, it gives

```
date : 1
day : monday
spend: 2
```

but  i am having problem it also gives me output like this when i give input like this e.g input : 1

```
output:
date :1
day : monday
spend:2
spend:1
```

for split i have written this code:

```
for (String token : line.split(":")) { // Splitting each line with ':'
                        if (!token.trim().equals(" day")) { // Adding token to list conditionally.
                            list.add(token);
                        }
                    }
```

is there any idea that could prevent "spend" from getting to split. i mean split should happen at date and day only at each line.

Comment: do you want split to happen on colon, except when preceded by "spend"?

Comment: yes line of string that conatins spend:... shd not be split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split on a colon, *except* when the colon is preceded by `"spend"`:

```
line.split("(?<!spend)\\s*:\\s*")
```

Comment: giving error ... Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: named capturing group is missing trailing '>'

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. Are you sure you are copying my code correctly? The error you are seeing would happen if you omitted the `!` - you must not have copied my code properly. Try copy-pasting it directly into your code.

Comment: i am witing like this:for (String token : line.split("(?<!spend)\\s*:\\s*")) { // Splitting each line with ':'
                        if (!token.trim().equals(" day")) { // Adding token to list conditionally.
                            list.add(token);
                        }
                    }

Comment: Yes - that is correct. To make sure, I copied your code into my IDE and it worked. There is something else going on here. Maybe you haven't rebuilt your code? Do you have "auto rebuild" enabled in your IDE?

Comment: i am using eclipse and done. ok if it is working at your then i make new may be software problm.

Comment: BTW you have a bug: You should remove the space before "day" in `token.trim().equals(" day")` because `trim()` removes leading/trailing spaces so it will never return `" day"` (with a space)

Comment: you can sent me file at this ID: darenhogg@gmail.com i will see. ok?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if this is what you wanted but you can use lookbehind in your split:

```
String s = "date : 1\nday : monday\nspend : 4\n";
String[] r = s.split("(?<!spend(\\s+)?):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
```

this will produce:

```
[date ,  1
day ,  monday
spend : 4
]
```

Comment: try it without spaces: `...spend:4`

Comment: @Bohemian, its easy to fix - look at the updated answer.